# how to set value for WSS -Time to Live in wcf services which is calling anoother SOAP service?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

how to set value for WSS -Time to Live in wcf services which is calling another SOAP service?

Comment: can you give me more detials?I don't quite understand your mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of the inactivitytimeout property in WCF.If more than the InactivityTimeout specified time interval passes with no activity, the session is aborted by the infrastructure and the channel faults.

You can configure it in the configuration file:

```
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Binding">
                <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

I set the timeout to 10 minutes. If the client-side does not send any messages to the server-side within 10 minutes, the connection will be interrupted.

For more information about reliablesession and inactivitytimeout,please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/reliablesession

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.reliablesession.inactivitytimeout?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1